# google map not loaded properly in android

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application i just try to load a google map.i tried the following code.the page is loading but it only shows the plus and minus symbol at the right down corner.how can i load the map properly.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


        }
    }

}
```

XML Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAoNg2iHJUuRsBBGytXKxkWVFe5RgjlsRU" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check your `Map API Key`....

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is some issue with your `Map api key`.
Please confirm you are doing as the same as explained tn this official document.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: please stop using `Mark as up, if i am right.` it is not a part of answer

Comment: @harini:please post your AndroidManifest.xml file code here.